# How to solve security issues joomla php in cpanel

Tags: php, html, ssl, joomla, cpanel

I have a project that was written in php using joomla 1.54 and the project is hosted on cpanel.The website is not opening and is giving this error upon launching it in a browser

Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from [www.websitedomain.com](http://www.websitedomain.com) (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards).

NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

I am new to php and joomla but i intent on at least making the project work so i can view content and redesign it using non-cms. How do i sovle the issue above.

Comment: This looks like you are missing a valid SSL; not a php issue.

Comment: `joomla 1.54` -- Holy Yikes!  Time upgrade first then fix anything that might not be working AFTER that.